# Can we add custom CSS class in \Drupal::messenger()->addStatus()?

Tags: theming, 9, status-messages

I did some research regarding adding custom CSS classes in the message but could not find the actual solution.

As per Drupal 9 documentation:

```php
\Drupal::messenger()->addMessage(t($message));

public function addMessage($message, $type = self::TYPE_STATUS, $repeat = FALSE);
```

I don't find the option to add CSS class. On the frontend, I would like to add custom CSS class `custom-messages--status` in the outputted `<div>` so that I can format it as desired:

```html
<div class="col-md-12 messages custom-messages--status">Successfully submitted.</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

`addMessage()` accepts a string or a MarkupInterface as its argument. If you intend to pass HTML to `addMessage()`, you need to construct a render array for that markup then explicitly render it. For example:

```
$build = [
  '#type' => 'container',
  '#markup' => t('Successfully submitted'),
  '#attributes' => ['class' => ['custom-messages--status']],
];
$message = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderPlain($build);
\Drupal::messenger()->addMessage($message);
```

Of course, you should inject these services when possible rather than using static `\Drupal::` calls.